# Penwidth in my graphviz installation doesn't work. Which package did I miss?

Tags: installation, version, graphviz

It has cairo, and I installed on cent os 5 linux and below is the dot-file and command I used to test it.

1.dot :

```
digraph {
    a [
    color ="#AA00AA"
        style="filled"
        fontcolor="cyan"
        pos = "0,0!"
      ]
    b [label = "yyy",pos = "10,10!"]
    a -> b[penwidth="6", color="red"]
    b -> c
}
```

command:

```
neato -Tps 1.dot -o 1.ps


dot -Tps 1.dot -o 1.ps
```

Comment: found answer: dot-V gives graphviz version 2.12. too old to have penwidth.  http://graphviz.996277.n3.nabble.com/Penwidth-doesn-t-work-Any-alternative-ways-to-bold-a-color-edge-td2919.html

Answer (score 0):

As the asker said in a comment:

> found answer: dot-V gives graphviz version 2.12. too old to have
>   penwidth. graphviz.996277.n3.nabble.com/… –  asker ask Sep 6 '13 at
>   16:09

and in the source:

> penwidth was added in January 2008

Here's the source for that information:

http://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:penwidth

Based on this repository: http://www.graphviz.org/pub/graphviz/ARCHIVE/

It's unlikely to be available in Graphviz until 2.20 (maybe 2.18) on.